Deploying TurboRepo with Next.js Frontend and Express.js Backend on Vercel
I am currently building a basic proof of concept for a monorepo using TurboRepo, featuring a Next.js front-end and an Express.js backend with Prisma ORM.
I can run my project locally without issues, but I would like to deploy it on Vercel. I am aware that Vercel now supports Express server deployment, but I haven't found helpful information on deploying both an Express server and a Next.js app within a TurboRepo monorepo.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure and deploy a TurboRepo with both a Next.js front-end and an Express.js backend on Vercel? Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the link to the POC
Thank you!
